# Javascript If else is executing if and a part of the else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an issue that I cannot understand why is happening. I have a commune If else but is executing the if and a part of the else, and this happens only the first time that is executed.

HTML code:

```
<div class="span3 options-search">
  <select id="condition[0]" name="condition[0]" onchange="checkCriterial(this.value,0);">                                                     
    <option value="2">Id</option>
    <option value="3">private</option>
    <option value="11">author</option>
    <option value="1">Date</option>
    <option value="4">externalId</option>
    <option value="5">Email</option>
    <option value="9">string</option>
    <option value="10">Date</option>
    <option value="6">numeric</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7">true-false</option>
    <option value="8">numeric</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="span1 criterial-search-0">
  <select class="span1" id="criterial[0]" name="criterial[0]">
    <option value="1">=</option>                     
  </select>
</div>
<div class="span3 condition-quicksearch-0">
  <select class="span2 search-value-0" id="valuevar[0]" name="valuevar[0]" ><option value="false">False</option> <option value="true">True</option></select>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
checkCriterial = function (condition, id) {
    if (condition == 1 || condition == 10) {
        $('.search-value-' + id).attr('placeholder', '31/12/2015').addClass("datepicker").attr("data-date-format", "dd/mm/yyyy").attr("data-link-format", "yyyy-mm-dd");
        $(".criterial-search-" + id).html('<select class="span1" id="criterial[' + id + ']" name="criterial[' + id + ']"><option value="1">=</option><option value="2">>=</option><option value="3"><=</option></select>');
    } else if (condition == 7) {
        $('.condition-quicksearch-' + id).html('<select class="span2 search-value-' + id + '" id="valuevar[' + id + ']" name="valuevar[' + id + ']" ><option value="false">False</option> <option value="true">True</option></select>');
        $(".criterial-search-" + id).html('<select class="span1" id="criterial[' + id + ']" name="criterial[' + id + ']"><option value="1">=</option></select>');
    } else {
        $('.condition-quicksearch-' + id).html('<input type="text" class="span3 search-value-' + id + ' search" id="valuevar[' + id + ']" name="valuevar[' + id + ']" />');
        $(".criterial-search-" + id).html('<select class="span1" id="criterial[' + id + ']" name="criterial[' + id + ']"><option value="1">=</option></select>'); //<- this is also executed
    }
};
```

I created a jsfiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/wr5p4xf7/

if you select a `date` option it will execute the if statement and the second line of the else.

the first thing that i checked has been the brackets and looks fine.

Any Idea?

Thanks All.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  It runs the first block and nothing in the else.  What makes you think it's running the else?  Also, you're not injecting valid HTML (perhaps that's the problem in your browser - it might be skipping the "invalid" options, making it look like the else has run) - you should use `&lt;` and `&gt;` rather than using `<` and `>` in your `option` tags.

Comment: Try to output some debug data to the console to see what happens and why.

Comment: As a general hint about debugging, don't start with the assumption that javascript if ... else is broken, start with the assumption that *you* did a mistake, it really helps finding the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because your **search-value-0** field is initialized as a select element, you need to remove the current **search-value-0**, create a new element input and just after this insert datepicker classes to element.

I've changed your fiddle to create the input inside the first condition and now it's working.

```
 if (condition == 1 || condition == 10) {
        $('.condition-quicksearch-' + id).html('<input type="text" class="span3 search-value-' + id + ' search" id="valuevar[' + id + ']" name="valuevar[' + id + ']" />');
            $('.search-value-' + id).attr('placeholder', '31/12/2015').addClass("datepicker").attr("data-date-format", "dd/mm/yyyy").attr("data-link-format", "yyyy-mm-dd");
            $(".criterial-search-" + id).html('<select class="span1" id="criterial[' + id + ']" name="criterial[' + id + ']"><option value="1">=</option><option value="2">>=</option><option value="3"><=</option></select>');
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wr5p4xf7/8/

Answer (score 0):

In my browser (Linux Ubuntu, Chrome 45), every loop is processed as expected :

- `checkCriterial()` is triggered whenever the first select element is clicked :

  - The value of `condition` depends on which option is selected in the selection box.
  - It processes `if (condition == 1 || condition == 10) { [...] }` when `condition` is either 1 or 10.
  - It processes `if (condition == 7) { [...] }` when `condition` is 7.
  - It processes `else { [...] }` when `condition` is anything but 1, 7 or 10.

See [**this modified Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wr5p4xf7/2/), where I alert some debug info.

If you prefer `console.log` for debugging instead of `window alert`, try [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wr5p4xf7/3/) instead.

---

What appears to be the problem, is that your forgot to replace your select statement with an input box when your condition is 1 or 10.

You did this correctly for your `else` condition, but seemed to have forgotten to do it for `if (condition == 1 || condition == 10) { [...] }`.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, only the first block of your `if`/`else` construct is executing.
To see this:

1. Visit your jsfiddle in chrome.
2. Hit F12 to open dev tools.
3. In the dev tools menu bar select Source
4. In the sources side bar that appears expand fiddle.jshell.net, then wr5p4xf7 and select index.
5. Place a breakpoint on line 51 of the (index) source that has opened.
6. Select Date in your fiddle.
7. Use the debugger controls to step through the execution path (e.g. F10 to step).

Comment: @Ergwuri : In my browser (Ubuntu, Chrome 45), everything works fine. What browser are you using for testing?!

Comment: @JohnSlegers It is working as expected for me too. I am merely explaining how the OP can observe this for his/herself. By first block I mean it is triggering the first condition since `condition` is `1`.

Comment: `checkCriterial()` is triggered whenever the first select element is clicked. The value of `condition` depends on which option is selected in the selection box.